# How to Match Against all words except those in parentheses? [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that gives me ids if the word `test` is exists.

```
SELECT `Topic`.`id`
FROM `topics` Topic
WHERE MATCH(`Topic`.`title`,`Topic`.`body`) AGAINST('+test' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Is there a way to filter it somehow? I need to get only ids where the word `test` is not in parentheses. For example, if we have:

```
id   text
1    some text test some text
2    some text (test) some text
3    some text (text test text) some text
4    test some text
```

Is there a way I can get only 1-st and 4-th ids by using Match Against?

Comment: What about something like: `WHERE text NOT LIKE '%(%test%)%'`

Comment: @Jordan this would pick up (text) test (text) as well, although the word test is not within parentheses.

Comment: @whitesiroi no, this cannot be achieved through fulltext search, since this would require the search to be aware of a word's context, but fulltext indexes index words only. Perhaps you can do it with regular expressions (rlike operator), but not with fulltext search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this cannot be achieved through fulltext search, since this would require the search to be aware of a word's context, but fulltext indexes index words only. Perhaps you can do it with regular expressions (rlike operator), but not with fulltext search.